# Overwhelming syntax on react-motion

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I wanted to use https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion but when I look at the very first example:

```
import {Motion, spring} from 'react-motion';
// In your render...
<Motion defaultStyle={{x: 0}} style={{x: spring(10)}}>
  {value => <div>{value.x}</div>}
</Motion>
```

I got overwhelmed with the ES6 syntax and the JSX syntax. I tried translating it on the [babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) but it strips out the JSX syntax:

```
"use strict";

React.createElement(
  Motion,
  { defaultStyle: { x: 0 }, style: { x: spring(10) } },
  function (value) {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      value.x
    );
  }
);
```

What does this translate to in pre-ES6 JSX syntax?

Comment: *"What does this mean in pre-ES6 syntax?"* exactly what Babel shows you. What specifically do you find confusing? The only thing that is es6 specific in the first example is the module import and the arrow function. Anything else is JSX or object literals.

Comment: @FelixKling, Sorry, I meant "What does this translate to in pre-ES6 JSX syntax?"

Comment: Simply replace the arrow function with a function expression. `function(value) { return <div>{value.x}</div>; }`. The result is your answer.

Comment: Are you asking about the module syntax or just the `<Motion></Motion>` part?

Comment: It does seem like the doc authors were more interested in looking cool using es6 syntax and having as few LOC as humanly possible, rather than getting the underlying concepts across.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import {Motion, spring} from 'react-motion';
// In your render...
<Motion defaultStyle={{x: 0}} style={{x: spring(10)}}>
  {value => <div>{value.x}</div>}
</Motion>
```

could be written equivalently as

```
var ReactMotion = require("react-motion");
var Motion = ReactMotion.Motion;
var spring = ReactMotion.spring;
// In your render...
<Motion defaultStyle={{x: 0}} style={{x: spring(10)}}>
  {function (value) { return <div>{value.x}</div>; }}
</Motion>
```

without ES6 features but using JSX.

They only two things that are very different (with links to appropriate docs):

- [The `import` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), which also uses a form that resembles (and works like) [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which allow you to concisely define functions

Also syntax like `<Motion defaultStyle={{x: 0}} style={{x: spring(10)}}>` is often confusing, but remember that `attr={}` allows you to pass an JS expression, and the expression is simply an object literal. This is functionally equivalent to:

```
var defaultStyle = {x: 0};
var style = {x: spring(10)};
<Motion defaultStyle={defaultStyle} style={style}>
```